# Stop Spring standalone service

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring Integration in my project.

We have a requirement that in case where we will have stop Spring standalone service if database goes down.

In Message listener when I persist the data into database I check if I get CannotGetJdbcConnectionException then stop the Spring service using applicationContext.close() method.

Problem here is if I received any message on to the Queue and database goes down.

I tried to close Spring service then all resource goes down except DefaultMessageListenerContainer that holds that message.

If I terminate the process manually then message goes into inbound Queue which is correct.

Is there any way I could stop Spring service forcefully and put the message back to Inbound Queue?

I hope I am clear with my point here.

Thanks
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the DMLC with `setSessionTransacted(true)` (`acknowledge="transacted"` when using the namespace to define the endpoints).

Then any in-flight messages will be rolled-back onto the queue.

Comment: I have already set acknowledge="transacted".<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
  id="jmsIn" channel="inbound" container="messageListenerContainer"
  acknowledge="transacted"></int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>. How do I close the session that is active that holds the messages when DB was down?

Comment: The container will stop when the context is closed; if it does not, it is likely that you have some application code that is stopping the thread from terminating. Take a thread dump with jstack or similar to figure it out.

Comment: DMLC that currenty hold the message is not getting terminated because message in still in transit and it has not moved to inbound or error code. So that thread is not getting terminated. Is it possible to move the message to error code manually like we can stop inbound adapter and then close the applicationContext

Comment: Closing the context will stop the thread unless your code is holding it up. As I said, you need to look at a thread dump to see why it's not terminating.